# set background on focus row cell in android list view

Tags: android, android-listview

i have developed an application that contain List view and data getting from Database and in database i have timing detail so i want implement like when i start list Activity(Main Activity) its automatic focus on Current timing detail on list view item and that cell being highlight with different background or color i giving too much effort on this but still not working , i used ListView.setselection method but getting null pointer Exemption error

my code is here..

```
 boolean isSelected = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ListViewAdapter.List.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    placeTime = (Date) format.parse(((PlaceRouteDetail) ListViewAdapter.List.get(i)).getTime());
                    hourPlaceTime = placeTime.getHours();
                    minutePlaceTime = placeTime.getMinutes();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (hour <= hourPlaceTime & minute <= minutePlaceTime) {
                    ListView.setSelection(i);
                    ListView.getChildAt(i).setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                    isSelected = true;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: I think you should move the logic inside the adapter, and in get view() method you should check for the position that must be selected and set a background color on that cell.

Comment: @Laura but i have List view in main Activity and when i am launching it, it gain Focus on specific item of List view

Comment: I think you should make a custom adapter in this case, because there is no method in Android which lets a certain row as highlighted (selected).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList mListItems;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mContext;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList arrayList){

    mListItems = arrayList;
    mContext = context;

    //get the layout inflater
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //getCount() represents how many items are in the list
    return mListItems.size();
}

@Override
//get the data of an item from a specific position
//i represents the position of the item in the list
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
//get the position id of the item from the list
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    // create a ViewHolder reference
    ViewHolder holder;

    //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

        // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
    String stringItem = (String) mListItems.get(position);
    if (stringItem != null) {
        if (holder.itemName != null) {
            //set the item name on the TextView
            holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
        }
    }

    if (position == 3) { // hardcoded position
        // highlighted row
        view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        // normal row
        view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }

    //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
    return view;

}

/**
 * Static class used to avoid the calling of "findViewById" every time the getView() method is called,
 * because this can impact to your application performance when your list is too big. The class is static so it
 * cache all the things inside once it's created.
 */
private static class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemName;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reach to layouts in adapter. The thing you should do is setting a variable for the position you want to highlight.

```
int highlightPosition = 3; // define your position somehow
```

Then you should check this position in your list view adapter.

```
class ReactionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        if(position == highlightPosition) {
            // highlight the row 
        }
    }
}
```

After you change the position just call notifyDataSetChanged of the adapter.

And I had to highlight my rows too once and I used TransitionDrawable for that. Use a transition drawable in the background of your row and start transition instead of changing the background color immediately. It looks better.

Create a drawable for background of row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_row_normal" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_row_highlight" />
</transition>
```

Set this in your row layout.

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_row"
```

So get the background drawable from view:

```
background = (TransitionDrawable) convertView.getBackground();
```

and start the transition.

```
background.startTransition(duration);
```

Finally your adapter should look like this:

```
class ReactionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        if(position == highlightPosition) {
            // highlight the row 
            TransitionDrawable background = (TransitionDrawable) convertView.getBackground();
            background.startTransition(duration);
        }
    }
}
```